# Can one look at philosophy under the light of fictionalism? What ideas follow from this thought process?

Tags: metaphilosophy, paradox, syllogism, fictionalism

I understand that [fictionalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fictionalism/) can be attributed to a majority of disciplines, the ones I am familiar with are modal fictionalism, mathematical fictionalism and moral fictionalism, so I was thinking can we apply the philosophical ideologies of fictionalism to philosophy itself if so then what would we want the outcome of this thought process to affect? What is the other phenomena/discipline that would be positively affected by fictionalism of philosophy?

My intuition tells me that philosophy is already inherently fictionalized. We just omit the fictional attribute because it is inherent. "Philosophical fictionalism" will kind of be redundant? I am not sure.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide us with your definition of "fictionalism" and show on some examples the usefulness of this tag.

Comment: @JoWehler I've emended to include a pointer to "fictionalism".

Comment: Thanks, I know this reference. But I cannot sort out the essence of the concept and identify some examples, which demonstrate the usefulness of the tag.

Comment: Fictionalism is apparently not redundant in philosophy since most of philosophy theories are kind of realisms or quasi-realisms. Fictionalism always helps bridge the gap of incomprehensible things such as quantum mechanics phenomena especially entanglement, and you could view MWI as fictions instead of reals conservatively...

Answer (score 2):

> My intuition tells me that philosophy is already inherently
> fictionalized.

I think moving absolute questions, like God, origins of life, origins of the universe, origins of intelligent Homo Sapiens - outside the scope of science (including philosophy) were intentional. They are mostly relegated to religious views.

Without taking these 'absolute unknowns' outside the scope of scientific research, it would be hard to complete any logic, test or theory with some level of certainty.

But the global (fictional) view on a subject is necessary from time to time (I guess).